# Using alpabet in automata

Tags: finite-automata, dfa

I was working on an automat.
Then, I have a question about the loop. Normally, I was working with three alpabets but I'm completed with this problem. The problem is:

{w  | w starts with 0 and has odd length, or starts with 1 and has even length}

I want to covert this algorithm to the Deterministic Finite Automaton (DFA) How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you found the solution in NFA? As you’re asking about how to convert the solution to DFA.

Anyway, let me propose a solution.

```
NFA:
States= {A,B,C}
Alphabet= {0,1,2,3}
Start state= A
Final states= {A}
Transitions=
(A,0,A)
(A,1,A)
(A,2,C)
(A,3,A)
(B,1,A)
(C,3,A)
```

If you look at that automata, it’s been actually in a form of DFA, right?
So you don’t need to convert it. You might make it complete by adding transitions to the death state.

```
States= {A,B,C,D}
Alphabet= {0,1,2,3}
Start state= A
Final states= {A}
Transitions=
(A,0,A)
(A,1,A)
(A,2,C)
(A,3,A)
(B,0,D)
(B,1,A)
(B,2,D)
(B,3,D)
(C,0,D)
(C,1,D)
(C,2,D)
(C,3,A)
(D,0,D)
(D,1,D)
(D,2,D)
(D,3,D)
```

Comment: Thank you bakka it is what I was looking for. Can I ask more please? Do you know how to convert to regular expression this language?

Comment: Please look at the method in your book about how to convert it...Then compare your result to my solution here: (1+3+01+23)*. I might be wrong..